# Use hitTest:withEvent: to return custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to use `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to return a custom object on the screen with variables intact.

I've tried:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    SLDSlide *selected = (SLDSlide *)[self hitTest:location withEvent:event];
}
```

and

```
SLDSlide *selected = (SLDSlide *)[super hitTest:location withEvent:event];
```

But it's telling me there is no `@interface` for these methods, and I'm not sure how to write one myself that will return the object I want (`SLDSlide`, which is a subclass of `UIImageView`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will find the frontmost `SLDSlide` object at a given point in the view controller's `self.view`.

```
SLDSlide *selected = nil;

for ( UIView *view in self.view.subviews )
{
    if ( [view isKindOfClass:[SLDSlide class]] )
        if ( CGRectContainsPoint( view.frame, location ) )
            selected = (SLDSlide *)view;
}

if ( selected )
    NSLog( @"found one: %@", selected );
```

Note that if the view hierarchy has multiple levels, then the code would need to search recursively through the hierarchy, so this is just for the case where all of the `SLDSlide` objects are subviews of the view controller's `self.view`.

Comment: It is getting the object but it's not retaining any of the object's custom variables. Any idea on how that could be done?